# How to remove specific children pages when using echo $children; in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, children, custom-wordpress-pages

UPDATE: Fixed it!!

```
<?php
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$root_parent_id."&sort_column=menu_order&echo=0&exclude=912");
            if ($children) {
            ?>
```

We are using the following php code in the page.php file to dynamically build our sidebar nav section; however, I need to exclude certain child pages from appearing. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

```
<?php
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$root_parent_id."&sort_column=menu_order&echo=0");
            if ($children) {
            ?>
            <div class="submenu">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $root_parent_id ); ?></h2>
                <ul>
                    <?php echo $children; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: look for where $children is first created.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Okay, I've updated my code example to show where $children originates from. I know I need to add some type of exclude statement, I just can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first line with the following code.  Update 12 with the IDs of your child pages that you want to exclude.

Note: I moved the parameters into $args as its easier to read and maintain,

```
$args = array(
    'title_li'     => '',
    'child_of'     => $root_parent_id,
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order',
    'echo'         => 0,
    'exclude'      => '12'
); 

$children = wp_list_pages($args);
```

Here is more info on [wp_list_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/).